# Multiple functions to write into a single log file using Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, logging

I have a Python file with contains a few functions. When the "main" function runs, it runs through the functions. Each function needs to write some text to the same single log file.

I have written the following codes. The file handler is declared here as global in each function. I am wondering if there is a better way to achieve this?

```
LOG_FILE_NAME = 'TestLog.log'
f = None

def log1():
    global f
    print 'log1 called'
    f.write('log1 result' + '\n')

def log2():
    global f
    print 'log2 called'
    f.write('log2 result' + '\n')

logFileDir = LOG_FILE_NAME
f = open(logFileDir, 'w')
log1()
log2()
f.close()
```

Comment: Use the python `logging` package? It's very simple to set up and use for a single file: https://docs.python.org/2/howto/logging.html#logging-to-a-file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expanding Tom Dalton's link ([docs.python.org/2/howto/logging.html#logging-to-a-file](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/logging.html#logging-to-a-file)):

```
import logging
logging.basicConfig(filename='example.log',level=logging.DEBUG)
logging.debug('This message should go to the log file')
logging.info('So should this')
logging.warning('And this, too')
```

will write this too a file

```
DEBUG:root:This message should go to the log file
INFO:root:So should this
WARNING:root:And this, too
```

in your example, you could use a global logger, and each function could invoke it

```
import logging
logging.basicConfig(filename='example.log',level=logging.DEBUG)

def log1():
    logging.info('log1')

def log2():
    logging.info('log2')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    log1()
    log2()
```

if you wanted multiple loggers, you can use `logging.getLogger()`, there is plenty of flexibility with the logging module, check out the documentation (in the link).

Answer (score 2):

One way is to write your own simple logging function as a closure:

```
def create_logger(log_filename = 'TestLog.log'):
    f = open(log_filename, 'w')

    def logger(text):
        f.write(text + '\n')

    return logger,f.close

logwrite,logclose = create_logger()

def log1():
    print 'log1 called'
    logwrite('log1 result')

def log2():
    print 'log2 called'
    logwrite('log2 result')

log1()
log2()
logclose()
```

It avoids having to use `global`, encapsulates the file object, simplifies the call, and enables you to use several different filenames by calling `create_logger` for each one required.  You might, for example, wish to add a date/time stamp to the log message, simply done in one place by enhancing the `logger` function.

Comment: You probably want to open the file in append mode.  Otherwise it will overwrite the file at each call.

Comment: @wallyk:  No it won't.  The `open` is only done once when `create_logger` is called.  The actual write is done by the returned `logger` function which is then called multiple times.